# coldfusion calling another case within a switch

Tags: coldfusion, switch-statement

I have a switch like thus (written in cfscript):

```
switch (something) {
  case "stuff":
    if(this eq that){
      writeDump("hello");
    } else { /* do other? */ }
    break;
  case "other":
    //do something else
    break;
}
```

In my `else`, I want to be able to tell it that I want the "other" case to be invoked.  Is this possible? (I seem to remember doing this in other languages.)

Comment: Sorry, your question sounds extemely unclear.

Comment: Could you suggest a way to improve it? basically in my else i want a "goto "other"" kind of command...

Comment: Sounds pretty clear to me, Sergii.

Comment: @AdamCameron I guess this is my bad English then. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no GOTO construct in CF, no.  And that's pretty much what you're asking for.

If your switch is really as simple as you indicate, and you want to fall through to the NEXT case when the condition is false, what you *could* do is to have the break statement in the true branch of the if clause, and have no break statement in the false branch.  Then when the false branch runs, processing will not exit the case when it's done; it'll fall through to the next case.

Comment: Flagging as correct because there is no goto statement in Coldfusion (as of version 9); however, Scott Stroz put a good answer too.

Comment: @Jarede: There's never been a `goto` in ColdFusion in any version, and I seriously doubt we'll ever see anything like it in future versions.

Answer (score 4):

As Adam explained, it is possible, here is some code to show how:

```
something = "stuff";
test = "more stuff";

switch (something) {
case "stuff":
  if(test eq "more stuff"){
    writeOutput("<p>Something</p>");
    break;
  } 
case "other":
  writeOutput("<p>something Else</p>");
  break;
}
```

Change the values of 'something' and 'test' to see different results. When using a switch in cfscript, if there is no 'break' then ColdFusion will continue processing the cases until it hits one.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware that's not possible. You'll need to use an if else statement, or nested is/else, instead of the switch.

```
something = "other";

if (something eq "stuff" and 1 eq 2) {
    writeDump("hello");
} else if (something eq "other") {
    writedump("other");
}
```